# error: SCmathlib: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, putty

I have written code for conjugate gradient in PuTTy C++. When I try to compile it, it throws the error below.

```
error: SCmathlib.h: No such file or directory
cg13.cc:11: error: '::main' must return 'int'
cg13.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
cg13.cc:38: error: 'sin' was not declared in this scope
cg13.cc:39: error: 'exp' was not declared in this scope
cg13.cc:50: error: 'exp' was not declared in this scope
cg13.cc:60: error: 'exp' was not declared in this scope
cg13.cc:72: error: 'exp' was not declared in this scope
cg13.cc:83: error: 'dot' was not declared in this scope
cg13.cc:87: error: 'dot' was not declared in this scope
cg13.cc:131: error: 'fabs' was not declared in this scope
cg13.cc:132: error: 'fabs' was not declared in this scope
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you trying to compile your code? What is "PuTTy C++"? What is SCmathlib? Why aren't you using the C++ standard `<cmath>`?